# Get method class inside decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have this code:

```
class Application(object):
    def cache(self, obj_to_cache):
        def decorator(f):
            print 'apply decorator'
            return f
        return decorator

app = Application()

class A(object):
    cache = []

    def add_cache(self, obj):
        self.cache.append(obj)

    def print_cache(self):
        print 'cache: ', self.cache

class B(A):
    @app.cache('Hello')
    def get(self):
        print 'get B'

    @app.cache('World')
    def another(self):
        print 'another B'

b = B()
b.print_cache()
```

Gets the result:

```
apply decorator
apply decorator
cache:  []
```

My question is: How could I access from Method `def decorator(f):` to object A and call `add_cache`?

The result I want is:

```
apply decorator
apply decorator
cache:  ['Hello', 'Word']
```

Comment: You can't access `self.cache` at the time the decorator is applied, because `self` refers to an instance, and no instances have been created yet at the time the class is created.  You could access `A.cache` directly, since it is a class variable, but you'd have to hardcode that in the decorator.

Comment: You seem to be confusing some usages in there.You seem to be confusing instance with class variables - beware of that. Maybe @Brenbarn hint to hardcode A.cache is the easiest way or you to go, if you really want to do this.

Comment: Thank you,I was really confused. 
The solution I need is:
`class A(object):
    var_test = []  

    @classmethod
    def add_to_var_test(cls, obj_to_cache):
        cls.var_test.append(obj_to_cache)
        def decorator(f):
            print 'apply decorator'
            return f
        return decorator

    def print_cache(self):
        print 'var_test: ', self.__class__.var_test

class B(A):
    @A.add_to_var_test('Hello')
    def get(self):
        pass

    @A.add_to_var_test('World')
    def another(self):
        pass

b = B()
b.print_cache()`